# Are Imaged that are not being displayed downloaded?

Tags: css, image

Let's say I have an Image, use it with display: none;
Are Client Browser downloding that image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does "display:none" prevent an image from loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading)

Comment: Yes, it still downloads the image if you are using a `<img>` tag. Now, if you choose to load the image from css `url('')` it will be downloaded only when showed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `display: none` only hides it on the screen, the CSS does not stop the request from image being downloaded to client.