# Different behavior with hidden html elements in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a `div` with `display:none` as `style` attribute value. In css, a background image url is set for this `div`. I simply don't want the request for the image to be fired until the `div` is visible later through some JS code. In **Firefox** , the network tab shows that the request is not issued which is as expected. But in **Chrome** developer tools I found that the request for the image is actually fired after the `DOMContentLoaded` event. What could be the possible reason of different behaviors with hidden elements in these two different browsers ?

**Markup:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .remoteAudioSoundButton{
            background: url("http://ourserverurl/images/image_lady.png");
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 2px black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='remoteAudioSoundButton' style="display:none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        console.log("inside onload");
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screenshots:**

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading

Answer (score 2):

Why not add the background to a specific class? This way the image will only be loaded when the specific class is added to the element.

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.remoteAudioSoundButton').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
.remoteAudioSoundButton{
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px black;
}
.visible {
  background: url("http://ourserverurl/images/image_lady.png");
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='remoteAudioSoundButton'></div>
<button>Toggle Class</button>
```

Comment: Nice. I am gonna do like this.

Comment: The downloaded image isn't rendered in IE8

Answer (score 2):

Here is documentation of different browser behavior:

http://justinmarsan.com/hidden-elements-and-http-requests/

Which says:

> Chrome and Safari (WebKit)
>
> WebKit downloads the file every time except when a background is
>   applied through a non-matching media-query. Firefox
>
> Firefox won’t download the image called with background image if the
>   styles are hidden but they will still download assets from img tags.
>   Opera
>
> Like Firefox does, Opera won’t load useless background-images.
>   Internet Explorer
>
> IE, like WebKit will download background-images even if they have
>   display: none;

So to answer the question of **why**:

A quick argument for either side:

**Firefox** -  *Don't load until the content is visible:* 
No reason to load something not being viewed, improve page load time.

**Webkit** - *Load the image on pageload:* So, perhaps JavaScript decides to make the element visible later, the transition might be choppy if the image is not preloaded, and any other number of arguments for preloading images.

And a brief discussion of the topic:

http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/11/do-hidden-elements-load-background-images/

Comment: So there is no workaround of this particular problem in pure HTML/CSS ?

Comment: no. but why does that matter? if you are already using JS, the method of setting the background-image style with a different class. as suggested by another answer, sounds like the best option

Comment: Yes, I agree. And this is what rarama suggested.

Comment: The downloaded image isn't rendered in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Browsers may load images that are related to elements that have `display:none;` set.

I have worked around this before by using a technique like this snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('showKitty').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var kitty = document.getElementById('kitty'); 
    kitty.src = "https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"; 
    kitty.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<h1>What Can JavaScript Do?</h1>
<img id="kitty" class="hidden">
<button id="showKitty">Show kitten</button>
```

Comment: So you have to manually set the src from JavaScript later. But what if the src attribute value is only known to the html/css designer ?  And the guy manipulating the page in JavaScript has only the task to show or hide the element.

Comment: Admittedly I'm both guys.