# is there a way to stop content from loading in min-width screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a responsive website and I have a video background for the first screen, I want to hide the video on the mobile devices to make the site load faster. for sure display: none; will not disable the content from downloading..
I tried those two javascript to disable the content from loading the content on smaller screens but it still loads on the background:

```
if (screen.width < 768){
var removeelement = document.getElementById("videoClass");
removeelement.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Or :

```
$("#videoClass").remove();
```

they do the same work of CSS tag : display-none.
Is there any way in javascript to prevent the content from loading the content in the background ?

Comment: Its depend on how you are loading video, Add condition before video loading.

Comment: Read [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading) and [link 2](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/)

Comment: I would make an if statement checking if the site is viewed from a mobile or not. Then, Inject the video code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bist way to solve this is like what **Laxmikant Dange** and  **VanderVidi** said , 
All those javascripts and jqueries are fine and working but the problem is with how I am loading the video..
I used this code for downloading the content only on screens with width>768

```
<video id="videoClass">
<!-- removed the content from here -->
</video>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if (screen.width > 768){
var showElement = document.getElementById("videoClass");
//pasted the content here:
showElement.innerHTML = '<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">';
}
});
</script>
```

this solved the problem and the content loads only on bigger screens now..
Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the bellowed code which will make html of the selected div  empty.

```
if(window.innerWidth <  768 )//screen.width < 768 
  {
   $("#videoClass").html("");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
if (screen.width < 768){
    $("#videoClass").empty();
}
```