# Is there a way to prevent img get requests from occurring using css or js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I can only use css and/or javascript, is there a way I can prevent a get request to an image from happening?

like this:

```
<img src="A.png"/>

img {
    src:none;
}
```

And this will prevent the GET request to `A.png` when the page loads.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can't set HTML attributes via CSS of course. The most you can do here with CSS, is set the image to display:none (and maybe width and height to 0 as well), but you must ensure that this CSS gets _applied_ before the browser encounters the img element.

Comment: Why exactly do you need it? You can have `data-src` set,that won't send the request. Then when you actually need to call the request, you set the `src` from `data-src`

Comment: Have a look at [Does “display:none” prevent an image from loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading)

Comment: The above is just pseudocode to show what I want. Also I can't modify the html, I can only put in my css/js.

Comment: @AndyHoffman The answers there give contradicting results. Do you know if it will load in IE11 (ie 10 rendering mode) or chrome 49?

Comment: Here's a test with browser behavior re loading assets. It's outdated but may be an interesting read: https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this should work for what you're looking for:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img").attr("src", "");
    });
</script>
```

It should replace the `src` attributes in all `<img>` tags. 
You could also remove the `src` attribute with `$("img").removeAttr("src")`.

Something *similar* in javascript would be:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].setAttribute("src", "");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Like in jquery, you can use `images[i].removeAttribute("src")` to remove the html `src` attribute altogether.
Both of these scripts are at the bottom of my html.
I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

there is a javascript way:

giving no source to img initially (= not doing a request) and changing it source via javascript afterwards

if you want to enter the URLs of the image in the dom use data-src attribute as ISuthan Bala mentioned

```
<img data-src="my-image.png" />
```

Easy setting data-src to src via jQuery for example