# How to send a request using html or css (no js) when element comes into viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, amp-html

I'm currently working with AMP-html in my project, which gives me no use of my own javascript on the front-end. There are built-in components, but nothing to fire a request when a certain element scrolls into the viewport.

I was wondering if there was an html/css hack in order to fire a beacon for analytics purposes. (maybe something similar to lazy-loading an image, when the url is the request url)

Thanks!

Comment: There may be a way to do this using AMP analytics. If you post the structure of your HTML and the specific section you wish to track, I may be able to illo a potential solution. But this is exclusively a post-process, Google analytics solution. I'm not aware of any other potential techniques.

Answer (score 3):

**Short of it:**

As far as I know, there is no way to do scroll-linked effects, delayed image loading, or "beacons" reliably without JavaScript.

---

**Long explanation:**

Browsers will request images up front for layout and DOM purposes, even if they're outside the current view. [The HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#img-available) says that when scripting is disabled browsers *may* obtain images synchronously or asynchronously, but if scripting is enabled it must get them immediately. The spec [indicates](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#concept-bc-noscript) scripting is only considered disabled if the user turned it off, the browser doesn't support it, or the current document is in a sandbox.*

* Basically iframes with a [sandbox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) that doesn't contain `allow-scripts` as part of the value.

[An old comment on another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22970996/251262) indicates there are other ways to try to prevent image loading, such as using `background-image`, but they're not the same across browsers and can't be triggered by scrolling alone.