# Does <video> autoplay pause when element not visible in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, blink

I have a **video** tag with the **autoplay** attribute on. It's "hidden" in that it's nested in a container with **display: none** applied.

However, CPU usage for this page's tab in Chrome seems idling high (around 20%). There is nothing else on the page.

Do video tags pause autoplaying when hidden? For reference, WebKit-based Safari in iOS 10 pauses autoplaying on the video tag when not visible on screen (https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/). But I'm unconfirmed if Chrome does, since it uses the Blink fork of Webkit.

*Chrome Mac 55.0.2883.75 (64-bit)*

Answer (score 0):

From the [w3c docs](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video):

> **autoplay** = "autoplay" or "" (empty string) or empty
>
> Instructs the UA to automatically begin playback of the video as soon
>   as it can do so without stopping.

Property `display: none` will only **prevent** the element from being displayed, it will be loaded nevertheless. The `display:none` does not preventing video from loading. So as video available to play it will be played.

Here is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading) about image loading with `display:none`.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good reference about display: none and image loading behavior. I do wonder if this still applies to video in Chrome though, since it's still up the browser vendors. The closest hint I can find so far is this: "Muted autoplay will work for any visible video element in any visible document, iframe or otherwise." So could I assume that it wouldn't work if it weren't visible? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay