# Chrome Loading Images With no "src" attribute and a "data-source"

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm writing a pretty simple function to only load the image that is required from a group of four potential images.  I have a different version based on size and based on whether or not the browser supports svg; so I don't want to load potentially* four sources for each image -  [ * *[sometimes browsers load images even if display is set to none](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12158540/1167442)* ].

---

(
**note**: *As I'm writing this question - I'm thinking that maybe I'm going about loading these images the wrong way, but this question remains*.)

---

Anyway, I have `img` tags with a `data-source` attribute for each image needed.  None of them have a `src` set at the moment, and I haven't written the js yet to do load the correct one.  However, Chrome is loading the image anyway.

When I look at the images when the page loads, the browser has created a `src` attribute for the first image in each set, and then populated it with the value from `data-source` for that image.

In other words - first image should show up in the browser like this:

```
<img data-source="my-image.png">
```

But instead shows up like this:

```
<img data-source="my-image.png" src="my-image.png">
```

Is it in fact Chrome that's doing this?  If so, why? *(Although I can guess)*.  And is this based upon some principle that would lead a web developer to reasonably expect this to happen (e.g. *"That's what data-attributes are for dumbass."* ) ?

Comment: This is not standard behavior for any browser. Are you loading any Javascript files/libraries on the page?

Comment: Yeah.  One of them could be doing it, but it's definitely not expected or desired.

Comment: I had a similar issue with ***src*** vs ***data-src***. My problem seemed to be fixed by replacing the ***data-src*** with ***data-original-src***. Although this is only a solution if you have control over the generation of the html.