# Are my images being loaded on Mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

On my webpage, I have a Carousel using following **CSS** & **HTML** code.

Will my mobile browser still load these images and use up bandwidth even though I have the background set to `display:none` when it's below 600px width?

---

**CSS:**

```
.item1 {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/1.jpg')
}
.item2 {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/6.jpg')
}
.item3 {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/5.jpg')
}
.item4 {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/3.jpg')
}
.item5 {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2.jpg')
}
.item6 {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/1.jpg')
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .item, .item1, .item2, .item3, .item4, .item5, .item6, #myCarousel4, #myCarousel 4 div {
        display: none
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel4">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item item1 active">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item item2">
 <img class="img-responsive">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item item3">
 <img class="img-responsive">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item item4">
 <img class="img-responsive">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item item5">
 <img class="img-responsive">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="item item6">
 <img class="img-responsive">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel4">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
</a> 
<a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel4">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/xetvLk6w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As long as your images are in the directory "/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/1.jpg".

You publish your website on a server in the folder "root", there you have the "index.html" and and the folder structur: "root/wp-content/uploads/...".

So where ever you open your Website, it will look for the directory and will find and load your images.

**EDIT**
When your display width will be under 600px the images will not be displayed. For a smarter css you can just use

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .item { 
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This will hide every div with the class "item", which all divs are containing in the example.

Comment: Cool! So if I'm on my mobile phone, it won't load the images as I've set it to display:none or will it still load them anyway?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Your media query does not seem to be firing, have you added this meta tag to your header? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: i dont even made an example :-? I dont know what you want to ask me :-( @NeelamKhan

Comment: You have answered the question with your code example @DominikNoll the styles inside the media query in the original question were wrong and that is  what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been answered here: [Does "display:none" prevent an image from loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading)

and there it's said

> Browsers are getting smarter. Today your browser (depending on the
> version) might skip the image loading if it can determine it's not
> useful.

It really depends on your browser. Some will load the images and some won't, as is stated in this answer to the above post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22970996/2700042

these are the essential findings discussed in the answer linked above

> So after digging further I found this, which explains how each browser
> handles loading img assets based on css display: none;
>
> Excerpt from the [blog post](http://justinmarsan.com/hidden-elements-and-http-requests/):
>
> Chrome and Safari (WebKit): WebKit downloads the file every time
> except when a background is applied through a non-matching
> media-query.
>
> Firefox: Firefox won't download the image called with
> background image if the styles are hidden but they will still download
> assets from img tags.
>
> Opera: Like Firefox does, Opera won't load
> useless background-images.
>
> Internet Explorer: IE, like WebKit will
> download background-images even if they have display: none;
>
> Something odd appears with IE6 : Elements with a background-image and display:
> none set inline won't be downloaded... But they will be if those
> styles aren't applied inline.

Answer (score 1):

display: none will not help you.

For readability, I'd place the "default" (mobile-first) css on top as:

```
.item1 {
  background-image: none;
}

...

/*note min and em */
@media all and (min-width: 40em) {
  background-image: url('bla.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I did wonder how much of a difference this would make - so it makes more sense to go mobile first when doing this?

Comment: Mobile first one of the basic principles in RWD.

Comment: "Mobile first one of the basic principles in RWD" - Arguably ;-)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk , I can't parse the amount of irony in your comment but that's ok. :) However both bootstrap, foundation and pureio (my favourite) uses min-width in ascending order.