# HTML - When does Bootstrap modal gets load?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am preparing a website using bootstrap which uses a lots of modals with images. I am concerned about the performance.
I want to know that when exactly the browser loads the modal.

- With the page loads?
- After the page loads?
- On click/trigger event?
- As per code flow?

Or something else?

Anyone please explain.

Comment: If you have images inside your HTML they will be loaded when you visit the page.

Comment: @makshh, no they wont, because the parent object has its display property set to none

Comment: @Campbell, I meant that all images will be DOWNloaded.

Comment: The answer to that is 'maybe' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading

Comment: Exactly, `display: none` doesn't mean your image won't be rendered/loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the modal is loaded when the page loads. However, bootstrap sets its css `display` property to `none` (Line 5876 in the bootstrap.css file). `display: none` means that the element **won't be rendered** until its display value changes.

**What this means:**
You should be fine, unless you plan on showing loads of modals at once. And by loads I mean *thousands* of them.