# CSS "display:none" doesn't prevent image loading?

Tags: css

I don't want to display some image on mobile site.

l tried CSS "display:none" , image disappear but it still loading **so that make mobile site slower**

How to css prevent image loading on mobile ?

Thank you.

Comment: `display` property has nothing to do with loading/unloading images.

Comment: There is some interesting information about how different browsers handle this situation in this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading/22970996