# load large number of images and set the first 100 to be visible

Tags: html, css, image

I have about 100.000 images - max 960 x 540px.

Is it recommendable to load all images at once but only the first 100 set to be visible on screen?

And how can I do that using CSS?

Something like:

```
.image {
    display:none;
}

.image:nth(0 - 100){
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Related: [Does “display:none” prevent an image from loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading)

Comment: I think you are going to run into performance issues with that many images on a single page.  CSS can hide them, but they are still loaded.  I think you might have to rely on a JavaScript solution to do what you want, and not slow down the browser

Comment: @ChrisBarr, could you give me an example or link for the javascript solution?

Comment: @puerto just search for "lazy-load" images, that' what you'd call this technique. Here are some examples: https://css-tricks.com/lozad-js-performant-lazy-loading-images/ and https://sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/

Answer (score 1):

There is no `:nth` selector in css, you need to use [`:nth-child` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child). Then update the selector to get the rest of the images(`101, 102,...` => `n + 101`) and then apply the style to hide them.

```
/* set default styles here */
.image {
    display:inline-block;
}

/* following would select 101, 102,... since value of 'n' starts from 0 */ 
.image:nth-child(n + 101){
    display:none;
}
```

---

In case there are some other siblings tags then use [`:nth-of-type` pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

```
.image:nth-of-type(n + 101){
    display:none;
}
```

---

Also refer : [Does "display:none" prevent an image from loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading)

Comment: and what about performances? Is it too heavy for an average comp?

Comment: @puerto : it's pure css, it won't make that much load  :)

Comment: but 100 000 images are in memory!

Comment: @puerto :  I'm not sure about how browser would handle the hidden img tags ( probably it would load )

Comment: @puerto : alternatively load src property when you are showing them( using javascript ) .... initially load src in some custom attribute ( eg : `data-src` )

Comment: btw your code doesn't work. Images 100+ are displayed. Did you test your code?

Comment: @puerto :  In order to work this, all `img` tags should be siblings ( without any other tags in between, if there then use `:nth-of-type( n + 101)` )

Comment: yes, they are siblings, but non of them are hidden.

Comment: @puerto :  try `:nth-of-type( n + 101)`