# How to change image source based on CSS prefers-color-scheme?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to integrate the new CSS [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) media query into my website. I have an `img` (image) element where the image is **very** dark blue. Which looks really bad with the new dark mode setting.

Is there a way to easily to change the source of this image based on that CSS media query?

I have considered having 2 `img` elements and set the `display` to hidden or not depending on that media query. But that feels like a little bit of a messy solution, and has it's drawbacks, such as the browser downloading both images.

I've also considered doing a CSS trick with `background-image` but I'm even more opposed to that than having 2 `img` elements and hiding and showing them.

Finally, of course I think this is possible using JavaScript. But this site specifically I'm very considered about compatibility, and some browsers allow users to turn off JavaScript all together, so a JavaScript solution I'm not a fan of in this case.

Is there any other way to do what I want here other than those solutions listed above?

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Could be interesting in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the [WebKit blog](https://webkit.org/blog/8840/dark-mode-support-in-webkit/) you can use the HTML [`picture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) tag to achieve this behavior.

Something like the following code is setup to use `night.jpg` when the color scheme is set to dark, but default to `day.jpg`.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="night.jpg" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
    <img src="day.jpg">
</picture>
```