# CSS Transition not firing on first hover

Tags: html, css, safari, transition

I'm trying a pretty basic transition but it's not right on Safari.. 
All I want to do is change background images from A to B on hover. However, the transition is not working the first time I hover over the element. 
On first hover, it is just instantly changing as opposed to gradually fading in/out.

JSFiddle here -- https://jsfiddle.net/RalphCSD/z9nx30co/4/

I'm using a Wordpress site if that makes any difference..

I've also included the HTML & CSS below. If anyone can see any errors that may be causing the issue I would greatly appreciate any help.

```css
.colBox {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://www.scatterboxshop.ie/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Scatterbox-Shop-CTA-Cushions.jpg");
  right: 0px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.colCon {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  max-width: 200px;
  color: white !important;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.colHead {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.colHeadLg {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.colP {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.moreArrow {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.colBox:hover {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://www.scatterboxshop.ie/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Scatterbox-Shop-CTA-Cushions-BG.jpg");
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hover-div {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.hover-div .stuff {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s;
}

.hover-div .stuff-hidden {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

.hover-div:hover .stuff {
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.hover-div:hover .stuff-hidden {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colBox">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="colCon">
      <h2 class="colHead">CUSHION COLLECTION</h2>
      <div class="hover-div">
        <div class="stuff">
          <p class="colHeadLg">Cushions</p>
          <p class="colP">Our luxury feather filled cushions are statement pieces each with a story to tell</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stuff-hidden">
          <p class="moreArrow">More <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the transition time from 0.5 seconds to 1.5 seconds:

```
.colBox {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://www.scatterboxshop.ie/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Scatterbox-Shop-CTA-Cushions.jpg");
  right: 0px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: For those wondering, I solved it by preloading the second image like so:

body:after{
 display:none;
 content: url(path/to/image-hovered.jpg) url(path/to/another-image-hovered.jpg);
}

Answer (score 0):

You have that jumping in every browser, just rest of them cache the hover image.
Basically, you gotta pre-load the image, which is on hover. Like, set it as background for parent element.

Comment: But actually, as long as you have the same, just darkened image, Y not to use overlay with black semi-transparent div, and avoid loading second image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply man! Much appreciated.. But I'm a little confused.. Do you mean declare two background images for the .colBox div? Thanks again man!

Comment: Seems like you've managed :)
The way you've mentioned in the comment for the next answer is not very common, but still ok.
But consider that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading
I would still recommend half-transparent overlay.

Comment: There is another option, was popular a while ago, allows to reduce number of requests: make 1 image of those 2: one above and one below, for example. And on hover - change the background-position - show only top half or bottom half.

Comment: For sure man , was someone else work and was trying to get it done as quick as possible.. Definitely the overlay is the way to go in future. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)