# How can I prevent images that are on my desktop site from loading on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, mobile-website

So I currently have a website that loads two different versions depending on screen size: one for desktop and one for mobile. For some reason, the images that I display on the desktop version of my site load on the mobile version.

Is there a way no prevent these images from loading on mobile to increase the performance/load time? Im not talking about the display:none; attribute/hiding the image on mobile, I'm trying to prevent them from even loading all together.

If you want to take a look at the site heres the link: https://rubyredsound.com

Comment: Alternatively use a jQuery plugin that Lazy Loads all images if not currently displayed.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to prevent these images from loading on mobile to
> increase the performance/load time?

**Yes.**

The `srcset` attribute is **explicitly intended** for downloading different image files depending on context.

The one caveat is that you *need to declare an image (or a fallback) for every environment*.

But that won't prevent you from using as your fallback an *equivalent-to-null* image (ie. a 1x1 pixel transparent png) declared inline using a `base-64 Data URL`, which looks like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

---

## `srcset` and `sizes` syntax:

The finished `<img>` element, with files indicated for desktop and mobile environments  will look like something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
     srcset="/my-image-folder/desktop.png 640w,
             data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== 1w"

     sizes="(min-width: 641px) 640px,
            (max-width: 640px) 1px"

     alt="Alternative Text for My Image"
/>
```

This `<img>` element will *only* download and display the `desktop.png` image if the browser viewport width is `641px` or greater.

Otherwise it will display a `1x1` pixel transparent png.

---

**Working Example:**

```html
<h2>Narrow and Widen your Browser Viewport in Full Page</h2>

    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
         srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/620x100 620w,
                 data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg== 1w"
    
         sizes="(min-width: 641px) 620px,
                (max-width: 640px) 1px"

         alt="Alternative Text for My Image"
    />
```

---

## Browser support

For contemporary browser support for `srcset` and `sizes` attributes, see:

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset

---

## More Info (plus tutorial)

For more in-depth info and a tutorial on using `srcset` and `sizes` to build `Responsive Images`, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

---

### Update in 2021

The Data URL used in the answer above:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

works, but it's a bit scrappy and pretty unclear what it's supposed to represent (unless you already know what it is).

I've since realised that:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'/%3E
```

works just as well and is both shorter and cleaner and more human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

## [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and using background-images

Via CSS you can [prevent background images from loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading#answer-15346450) if not active on page load. Keeping that in mind you can hide an image *(or any element really)* from mobile on and start displaying them through a Media Query.

```
.myMobileImage {
  background-image: url(...);
}

.myDesktopImage {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .myMobileImage {
    display: none;
  }

  .myDesktopImage {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(...);
  }
}
```

As for personal preference I keep the mobile first approach in mind, declaring mobile styles first and overwriting them with Media Queries afterwards for bigger resolutions.

Comment: It still will load the image source. The OP wants to prevent loading image for performance boosting.

Comment: @The_ehT I've updated my answer, this should indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 ways that we can fix this issue:

1. Using picture tag.
2. Making the image a div with a background.
3. Lazy loading (native or with a plugin).
4. Content-visibility.

Details are in : [link](https://www.machmetrics.com/speed-blog/how-to-prevent-hidden-images-from-loading-on-responsive-designs/)

Answer (score 0):

I see you added JQuery tagg so :

```
<figure class="image"></figure>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if(w >= 600){
      $(".image").html("<img src='big-image.jpg'/>")
    }
    else{
      $(".picture").html("<img src='small-image.jpg'/>")
    }
});
```

There are other great solutions too (not supported in old browsers), take a look at image srcset     `<img srcset ... />`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images