# How do I embed an image on a canvas (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to embed an image into a canvas so that I can draw lines over the image with the canvas. However, I can't seem to get the image to appear inside the canvas. Here's the code I have (HTML then JS):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"  style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; position: relative; z-index:3; top:10em; width: 30em; height: 20em; left: 22em;"></canvas>
    <img src="mapfinal.png" id="mapPic" style="display: none;"/>
```

javascript

```
        var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var map = document.getElementById("mapPic");
        ctx.drawImage(map, 20, 20);
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: "var c = document.getElementById("canvas");" the selector should be "myCanvas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be one of two things. The most likely issue is that the image is not yet loaded before you try to draw it. To fix this, add an `onload` event listener to the `img` element to draw it once the image has loaded.

```html
<img src="mapfinal.png" id="mapPic" onload="drawCanvas" style="display: none;"/>

<script>
function drawCanvas() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var map = document.getElementById("mapPic");
  ctx.drawImage(map, 20, 20);
}
</script>
```

The other issue might be that since the `img` element is set to `display: none` the [browser isn't loading the image at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading). Depending on the browser it may or may not load it. If you don't want the image to dispaly a better approach would be to create it through JavaScript.

```js
var map = new Image();
map.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(map, 20, 20);
};
map.src = 'mapfinal.png';
```

Comment: The second solution fixed my problem thank you so much!