# Why does `display: none` not load background image?

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time to wrap my head around this [quiz question](https://davidshariff.com/quiz/):

On page load, will `mypic.jpg` get downloaded by the browser?

```css
#test1 {
    display: none;
}
#test2 {
    background-image: url('http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random-pictures-116.jpg');
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
    <span id="test2"></span>
</div>
```

The answer is no. Why is that? Trying above doesn't load the image. But loading happens when I switch to `display: block;`

Does that have something with element space to be preserved using hidden visibility?

I am also confused because the previous question says `display: none` does load the background image although not in this case with a hidden descendant, and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading) talks about browsers are getting smarter and prevent the loads. So where is the truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this interesting because I didn't know about that. To conclude the image won't load if the item or one of its parents settings is `display: none`. Is it because browsers get smarter? I don't think so. I tried the following:

```css
#test1 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
   <img src="http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random-pictures-116.jpg"/>
</div>
```

In the Network tab of the developer-tools you can see that the image gets loaded. So it differs from your example. My thought is that `display: none` does not draw the element (fact) and so no style will be applied to itself or one of its childs (thought). **Basically  `background-image: url('...');` won't be executed because there is no need in applying the style to this element because it won't draw anyway.**

I hope this helped you understand :)

Comment: So as the `img` tag exists in the HTML it will be loaded but, like you said, the background-image won't as there's no need for it. Makes sense

Comment: Excactly. Because css is styling and why should the browser style a element that won't be rendered.

Comment: I am still lost `display: none` loads the background image, as the previous quiz problem and your snippet say, but not in the example above with child `visibility: hidden` element. How come?

Comment: @MaximeHelen It has nothing to do with `visibility: hidden`. If you want to load a image as background on a element which you can do by using `background-image: url('some-url')` then the image won't load if its or some of its parents has `display: none`. If you use the `<img src="some-url" />`it will load. The reason is that the browser only applies css or simply style to elements that render. An element with `display: none` won't render, so the image does not load if you use `background-image`. But the `<img />` will always load the image because thats the behavior of that element. :)

Comment: "An element with display: none won't render, so the image does not load if you use background-image", have you ran above script with network tab opened?

Comment: Ok I have re-read everything. Is the rule of thumb here the following: "`display: none` element will never make its descendants to render, so browsers won't bother loading eventual CSS imports from these children?"

Comment: @MaximeHelen Yes I did test it with network tab opened. Yes thats correct.