# Bootstrap 5 - display different responsive images for different breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5. I want to use an `img` tag to display a different image for mobile/tablet/desktop. I'm trying with this code but I'm unable to set correctly the breakpoints for the wrapper divs using the `display` utilities of the bootstrap framework.

If is possible, I want to have three image tags instead of three different divs that take the 100% of the window height.

If you see the code, I have a sort of modal to display on top of the background image that needs to fit for each breakpoint all the screen space available. I've tried with `img-fluid w-100 h-100` classes but the result isn't really nice and I can't crop the background. I'm using vue for the front-end, I'm not a front-end dev.

Thank you.

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row m-0">
<!-- This div with the image needs to be displayed only on mobile sm breakpoint -->
      <div class="col-lg-12 d-md-none d-lg-none d-sm-block p-0">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="@/assets/sm-background.png">   
      </div>
<!-- This div with the image needs to be displayed only on tablet md breakpoint -->
      <div class="col-lg-12 d-none d-sm-none d-lg-none d-md-block p-0">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="@/assets/md-background.png">   
      </div>
<!-- This div with the image needs to be displayed only on desktop lg breakpoint -->
      <div class="col-lg-12 d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block p-0">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="@/assets/lg-background.png">   
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mx-auto position-absolute" id="checkModal">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4>Age verification required</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            
            <input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="birthDate" >
            
            <input type="passwrd" class="form-control" v-model="passwor" >

            <button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="unlockContent()">Conferma</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      birthDate: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  methods: {
    unlockContent() {
      console.log(this.birthDate, this.password);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
/* #app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
} */
#checkModal {
  top: 14%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
</style>

´``
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>***Note:** Section 1 answers the original question (`d-*` usage) but is [not recommended for images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#why_cant_we_just_do_this_using_css_or_javascript) as browsers may preload hidden images. However, `d-*` classes are still useful to display other elements by breakpoint.*</sub>

---

### 1. `d-*` classes

Bootstrap classes are [mobile first](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#core-concepts), so we don't need to define every breakpoint. Whatever we define at smaller breakpoints will cascade up to larger breakpoints until overridden.

So assuming OP's device definitions, we can use these `display` classes:

| DEVICE | SCREEN SIZE | CLASSES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mobile | visible below `md` | `d-md-none` |
| tablet | visible only on `md` | `d-none d-md-block d-lg-none` |
| desktop | hidden below `lg` | `d-none d-lg-block` |

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- visible below md -->
<img class="d-md-none img-fluid w-100" alt="mobile alt text" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50/8da0cb/000000?text=600x50+for+breakpoint+%3C=+sm">
<!-- visible only on md -->
<img class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none img-fluid w-100" alt="tablet alt text" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x75/fc8d62/000000?text=900x75+for+breakpoint+==+md">
<!-- hidden below lg -->
<img class="d-none d-lg-block img-fluid w-100" alt="desktop alt text" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x100/66c2a5/000000?text=1200x100+for+breakpoint+%3E=+lg">
```

**Expanded cheatsheet for [hiding elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements):**

```
SCREEN SIZE            CLASSES
---------------------------------------------------
hidden on all          d-none
hidden only on xs      d-none d-sm-block
hidden only on sm      d-sm-none d-md-block
hidden only on md      d-md-none d-lg-block
hidden only on lg      d-lg-none d-xl-block
hidden only on xl      d-xl-none d-xxl-block
hidden only on xxl     d-xxl-none
hidden below sm        d-none d-sm-block
hidden below md        d-none d-md-block
hidden below lg        d-none d-lg-block
hidden below xl        d-none d-xl-block
hidden below xxl       d-none d-xxl-block
---------------------------------------------------
visible on all         d-block
visible only on xs     d-block d-sm-none
visible only on sm     d-none d-sm-block d-md-none
visible only on md     d-none d-md-block d-lg-none
visible only on lg     d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none
visible only on xl     d-none d-xl-block d-xxl-none
visible only on xxl    d-none d-xxl-block
visible below sm       d-sm-none
visible below md       d-md-none
visible below lg       d-lg-none
visible below xl       d-xl-none
visible below xxl      d-xxl-none
```

---

### 2. `<picture>` element (recommended for images)

Browser behavior for preloading hidden images has been inconsistent [over time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158668/13138364) and [across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22970996/13138364). Since loading hidden images hurts page load times, it's recommended to [avoid the `d-none` approach for images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#why_cant_we_just_do_this_using_css_or_javascript).

**Best practice for breakpointed images** (aka "[art direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#art_direction)"):

1. Use [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) with multiple [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) tags conditioned on [`media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#the_media_attribute) strings.
2. Since css classes don't work in [`media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#the_media_attribute) strings, use bootstrap's [breakpoint pixels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints):

   | BREAKPOINT | DIMENSIONS |
   | --- | --- |
   | `sm` | ≥576px |
   | `md` | ≥768px |
   | `lg` | ≥992px |
   | `xl` | ≥1200px |
   | `xxl` | ≥1400px |

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<picture>
  <!-- show this up to sm -->
  <source media="(max-width: 596px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/600x50/8da0cb/000000?text=600x50+for+breakpoint+%3C=+sm">
  <!-- else show this up to md -->
  <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/900x75/fc8d62/000000?text=900x75+for+breakpoint+==+md">
  <!-- else show this -->
  <img class="img-fluid w-100" alt="alt text for all sources" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x100/66c2a5/000000?text=1200x100+for+breakpoint+%3E=+lg">
</picture>
```

Comment: The recommended way to display responsive images is discussed in this MDN article:  [Responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#art_direction) *(specifically read the "Art Direction" topic)*.

Comment: @Vino I simply have three images of different sizes that will fit the breakpoint. I'm not deisgner so I was looking for a quick css trick to get the things in order ;)