# What is the modern way to keep images loaded in the background?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, image

I have an app which can switch between views on different subsets of a medium number of images (well below an acceptable amount to cache). I'm finding that when switching views, the browser sometimes asks the server if images are up-to-date before using the cached copy. The logic for doing so seems complex, and though I am interested in it, that isn't the focus of the question.

What ends up happening is the server sends back [304](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) (not modified), but the delay causes image pop-in. The effect is something like [changing these cats](https://codesandbox.io/s/cats-77duy9):

[image: changing cats]

It's no problem for me to keep all of my images loaded. It seems that this [used to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837464/12162258) with `display: none` but [is no longer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158668/12162258). However, [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) seems to do the trick. Look at [those smooth cats now!](https://codesandbox.io/s/cats-forked-tuev5q?file=/src/App.tsx)

[image: smooth cats]

So, what is the mid-2022 way to do this? Or am I being completely wrongheaded about the whole thing and should be thinking in an entirely different way about the problem?

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript) has been floated as containing much useful information, and while that's definitely true, I wanted to highlight how the [linked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cats-forked-tuev5q?file=/src/App.tsx) is addressing the problem, namely:

```
// webpack/react style image import
import cat001 from "./images/cat001.png";
import cat002 from "./images/cat002.png";
...
const CATS = [ cat001, cat002, ... ];
...
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Keep all the cats loaded all the time! */}
      {CATS.map((cat) => (
        <img key={cat} src={cat} alt="a cat" hidden />
      ))}
    ...
    </>
  );
}
```

This seems like a nice `JSX/TSX` solution, whereas it feels less idiomatic to me to load up [Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) in a random array somewhere, so the question might be more specific to the react domain than I initially indicated.

Comment: it really depends on how you're getting the new set of images ... I'd be inclined to do something like what done in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript ...

Comment: That seems sensible. How about in the `import imgName from "imageFile"` webpack via react case that's used in the sandboxes I linked?

Comment: I can see how you might say "the same way," but I guess I'm asking is there a preferred `TSX`-ey way like I used with `<img ... hidden />`.

Comment: I know you tagged the question "reactjs" and "typescript" ... but there was no mention of it in the question, and I don't usually follow links in questions ... so, in short, I have no idea how to do it in reactjs since I don't use reactjs

Comment: Understood. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: note: `CATS` is just an array of url's ... so, I imagine the code I linked to applies

Comment: I am kind of coming around to that... Why not just add another constant that keeps them loaded, right? I'll see if anyone chimes in about `<img hidden />`, but this might be a dup after all.

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe - you probably have to do something special since it's react